# Artificating when resizing scatter3D-Plot in R

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

I'm using MacOS 10.14.1 Mojave, RStudio 1.1.643 and rgl package.

I'm trying to create a 3D-Plot of a multiple linear regression model in R for my statistics homework. The code itself is fine since the plot is displayed in the way I want it to. However, whenever I try to resize the window, the whole plot gets screwed.

Check below for some sample images:

[image: So the scatter3D-plot is fine but a bit small]

When I resize the image, this starts to happen:

[image: The resized scatter3D-plot]

Here's the code I use:

```
library(rgl)

# 3D-Plot
scatter3d(df_babies$wtMother, df_babies$wtBaby, df_babies$smoke,
          xlab = "Weight Mother",
          ylab = "Weight Baby",
          zlab = "Smoke",
          revolutions=5)
```

Note, that when I set revolutions to 1 the problem disappears. Still, it's a very strange problem and I couldn't find any solutions through Google-search. I have the feeling that the problem is connected to me updating to MacOS Mojave. Does anybody know a fix to this problem? The 3D-plot is run in XQuartz. I have updated XQuartz but without any improvements.